# Hibernate @SequenceGenerator return incorrect value in MS SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", schema = "MD", sequenceName = "sq_base_class")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Hi! I have entity which using MS SQL Sequence for generating ID, but value is incorrect.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BCL'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'MD.BASE_CLASS'. The duplicate key value is (551009).
```

Example: SequenceGenerator set ID = 551009, but `select next value for md.sq_base_class` return 551115. How to resolve it?
Hibernate-version: 5.3.10.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you lost the allocation size = 1 in @SequenceGenerator